# Java, how to extract some text from a large file and import it into a smaller file

Tags: java, xml, text, io

I'm relatively new to Java programming and am trying to create an application which will help some colleagues.

The background of what I am trying to do is, read the content of a large file, upto and possibly more than 400,000 lines, which contains XML but is not an valid XML document, as its kind of a log.

What I am trying to do, is build an application where a user enters a unique ID, this then scans the document to find if it exists, if it does, and often the unique ID occurs a few times in the produced XML, then I want to traverse backwards to a node ID of `<documentRequestMessage>` , then copy everything from that node to its closing node, and put that into it's own document.

I know how to create the new document, but am struggling to find out how to essentially 'find backwards' and copy everything to the closing tag, any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to implement of either of the 3 suggestions thus far.

The ***correlationId*** is the unique reference previously mentioned.

The current code I have, which works and outputs the findings to the console, is

```
String correlationId = correlationID.getText();
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
System.out.println("Looking for " + correlationId);
int lineCount = 0;
String line;

while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    lineCount++;
    int indexFound = line.indexOf(correlationId);

    if (indexFound > -1) {
        System.out.println("Found CorrelationID on line " + "\t" + lineCount + "\t" + line);
    }
}

bf.close();
```

Any further help greatfully appreciated, I'm not asking for someone to write it for me, just some really clear and basic instructions :) please

EDIT 2

A copy of the file I'm trying to read and extract from can be found [here](http://db.tt/Sw0C4tWL)

Comment: Question - how do you know it's not valid XML?  Can you post a sample of what is "invalid" about it?

Comment: @SeanBright the reason I know it's not valid XML, is because

1) XMLSpy will not validate it.  2) It contains multiple <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> (585 entries)!  3) Plus also comments which I don't believe are proper XML comments, eg  [2013-05-29 12:18:57,626] Default : 4''# DocumentCompositionLogger sca.component.mediation.java.Custom1322734159344 INFO  - requestDocumentProductionPackG02 request payload received>>>>>>  I have copied a file to here so you can see the whole doc which I am trying to read, which can be found [here](http://db.tt/Sw0C4tWL)

Comment: @Gilbert's suggestion seems very straightforward, can you tell what trouble are you having with implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

While you are reading forward through the file looking for your unique ID, keep a reference to the most recent `documentRequestMessage` that you encounter.  When you find the unique ID, you'll already have the reference that you need to extract the message.

In this context, "reference" can mean a couple of things.  Since you are not traversing a DOM (because it's not valid XML) you will probably just store the position in the file where the `documentRequestMessage` is.  If you're using a `FileInputStream` (or any `InputStream` where `mark` is supported), you can just `mark`/`reset` to store and return to the place in the file where your message starts.

Here is an implementation of what I believe you are looking for.  It makes a lot of assumptions based on the log file that you linked, but it works for the sample file:

```
private static void processMessages(File file, String correlationId)
{
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        boolean capture = false;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        String lastDRM = null;
        String line;

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String trimmed = line.trim();

            // Blank lines are boring
            if (trimmed.length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            // We only actively look for lines that start with an open
            // bracket (after trimming)
            if (trimmed.startsWith("[")) {
                // Do some house keeping - if we have data in our buffer, we
                // should check it to see if we are interested in it
                if (buffer.length() > 0) {
                    String message = buffer.toString();

                    // Something to note here... at this point you could
                    // create a legitimate DOM Document from 'message' if
                    // you wanted to

                    if (message.contains("documentRequestMessage")) {
                        // If the message contains 'documentRequestMessage'
                        // then we save it for later reference
                        lastDRM = message;
                    } else if (message.contains(correlationId)) {
                        // If the message contains the correlationId we are
                        // after, then print out the last message with the
                        // documentRequestMessage that we found, or an error
                        // if we never saw one.
                        if (lastDRM == null) {
                            System.out.println(
                                    "No documentRequestMessage found");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(lastDRM);
                        }

                        // In either case, we're done here
                        break;
                    }

                    buffer.setLength(0);
                    capture = false;
                }

                // Based on the log file, the only interesting messages are
                // the ones that are DEBUG
                if (trimmed.contains("DEBUG")) {
                    // Some of the debug messages have the XML declaration
                    // on the same line, and some the line after, so let's
                    // figure out which is which...
                    if (trimmed.endsWith("?>")) {
                        buffer.append(
                                trimmed.substring(
                                    trimmed.indexOf("<?")));
                        buffer.append("\n");
                        capture = true;
                    } else if (trimmed.endsWith("Message:")) {
                        capture = true;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Can't handle line: " + trimmed);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (capture) {
                    buffer.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                /* Ignore */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is read the contents of the file and look for `<documentRequestMessage>` element. When you find one of the above elements, read till you find `</documentRequestMessage>` and store it in a list so all the `documentRequestMessage` will be available in a list.

You can iterate through this list at the end or while adding to list to find the unique id you're looking for. If you find it write to XML Files or ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your log is a series of `<documentRequestMessage>` contents.

Don't scan the log at all.

Read the log, and each time you encounter a `<documentRequestMessage>` header, start saving the contents of that `<documentRequestMessage>` block into a block area.

I'm not sure if you have to parse the XML or you can just save it as a List of Strings.

When you encounter a `</documentRequestMessage>` trailer, check to see if the ID of the block matches the ID you're looking for,

If the ID matches, write the `<documentRequestMessage>` block to an output file.  If the ID doesn't match, clear the block area and read to the next `<documentRequestMessage>` header.

This way, there's no backtracking in your file reading.